# Insisting on "Coding Style", "Naming Conventions" and "Documenting the Code"

Tags: coding-style, documentation, naming-conventions, project-management

I really don't know it this question fits stackoverflow and so sorry if it doesn't. I will really appreciate it if you let me know where should I ask such Qs.

Working in an small company as head of development, this always annoys me:

**How much should I insists on "Coding Style", "Naming Conventions" and "Documenting the Code"?**

As far as know (and learned), programmers really HATE being reminded about these things, specially documenting. But, on the other hand, these are really essential in lots of ways.

Comment: Ehm, let it be, but anyway this question would be better suited on Programmers.SE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How much should I...

**Much.**

Not *too much,* but enough. Coding style and naming conventions are an important part of the quality of the code a programmer writes. If I were to employ programmers, and there were two candidates having written the following code snippets:

One:

```
int main(int argc,char*argv[]){
int a=atoi(argv[1]);
int b=atoi(argv[2]);
printf("%d+%d=%d\n",a,b,a+b);
return(0);
}
```

Two:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int a = atoi(argv[1]);
    int b = atoi(argv[2]);
    printf("%d + %d = %d\n", a, b, a+b);
    return 0;
}
```

I would choose the second one for sure.

Documentation? That's very important also. Code should be properly documented - I mean, the documentation must be clean, concise, written using good English ("diz funktion iz calculate teh sum of two params" is unacceptable!) but it should also not be too long - good code is readable and self-explanatory.

Comment: Thanks. That totally makes sense about hiring someone new and I am totally agree with you. But my problem is mostly with people whom are already there! I really don't know if I should repeat all the time these thing or I should fire them!!

Comment: @MBZ The combination of the two. Tell them a few times to write proper code. If they continue writing crap, then get rid of them.

Comment: I will wait afew more days for other answers (if any) and then choose the best. Thanks again :)